# VBScript can't write the output from another file

Tags: file, text, vbscript

I have an input file like this:

```
**********************************************************
* NAME           : CONTROLLER                                                          
* FUNCTION       : NOTHING IMPORTANT                                           
* BEGIN DATE     : 31/07/13                               
* TIME BEGIN     : 23.39.17.75                            
**********************************************************
* DATA INPUT READ  : 000000540                            
**********************************************************
* NAME           : CONTROLLER                                                          
* FUNCTION       : NOTHING IMPORTANT                                           
* BEGIN DATE     : 28/04/13                               
* TIME BEGIN     : 22.19.35.22                            
**********************************************************
* DATA INPUT READ  : 000008940                            
**********************************************************
```

I want take the date, time and data and move in another output file formatted like this way:

```
31/07/13  23.39.17.75  000000540
28/04/13  22.19.35.22  000008940
```

As far now i tryied: EDITED

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objFSO 'File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim objInputTS 'Text Stream Object
Set objInputTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\Desktop\input.txt", ForReading, False)
Dim objOutputTS 'Text Stream Object
Set objOutputTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\Desktop\output.txt", ForWriting, True)



 Do Until objInputTS.AtEndOfStream
    Dim strLine
    strLine = objInputTS.ReadLine()

    c1 = "* BEGIN DATE"
    'WScript.Echo Len(c1)
    c2 = "* BEGIN DATE"
    'WScript.Echo Len(c2)
    c3 = "* DATA INPUT READ"
    'WScript.Echo Len(c3)

    If (Instr(strLine, 13) = "BEGIN DATE") Then objOutputTS.WriteLine(Mid(strLine, 20))

    If (Instr(strLine, 13) = "TIME BEGIN") Then objOutputTS.WriteLine(Mid(strLine, 20))

    If (Instr(strLine, 18) = "DATA INPUT READ") Then objOutputTS.WriteLine(Mid(strLine, 22)) 
Loop

objOutputTS.Close()
objInputTS.Close()
```

But in my output.txt file nothing appears. I think the problem is `*` but i don't know. I tryied in all ways. I can't find a way out. What's wrogn in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
If (Left(strLine, 12) = "* BEGIN DATE ") ...
```

with

```
If Instr(strLine, "BEGIN DATE") then
   strLineSplit = Split(strLine, ":")
   objOutputTS.WriteLine(Trim(strLineSplit(1)))
end if
```

or something to this effect.

EDIT:

Within your loop:

```
Dim beginDate, endDate, dataInputRead 

strLine = objInputTS.ReadLine()

If Instr(strLine, "BEGIN DATE") then
    strLineSplit = Split(strLine, ":")
    beginDate = Trim(strLineSplit(1))
end if

If Instr(strLine, "END DATE") then
    strLineSplit = Split(strLine, ":")
    endDate = Trim(strLineSplit(1))
end if

If Instr(strLine, "DATA INPUT READ") then
    strLineSplit = Split(strLine, ":")
    dataInputRead = Trim(strLineSplit(1))
    objOutputTS.WriteLine(beginDate & " " & endDate & " " & dataInputRead & Chr(13) & Chr(10))
end if
```

Comment: Ok now it works.. The only one little problem is the formatt of text. It's `31/07/13
23.39.17.75
000000540
31/07/13
23.39.17.75
000000540` line by line... And i want separate the 2 things with only 2 rows.

Comment: Append a line break to the end... something like & Chr(13) & Chr(10) (if memory serves me right).  So objOutputTS.WriteLine(Trim(strLineSplit(1)) & Chr (13) & Chr(10))

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner - wasn't trying to elude.  For the sake of accuracy (and perhaps efficiency), I prefer Instr and Split functions over Left and Mid functions if/when possible.

Comment: @Di Vero Labs - with Chr it's perfect but i have to start a new line with the other datas..

Comment: @DiVeroLabs - If the task is to find 'needles' at the start of strings (Left(, looking for them anywhere in the string (InStr) is a mistake.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner - Agreed, hence the 'if/when possible'.  Based on the data input that was provided, and from what I gathered he was trying to accomplish, I suggested this route.  Otherwise, I agree with your point 100% and appreciate you pointing it out.

Comment: @David_D - see edit for a suggestion on getting the output formatting you appear to be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Left(strLine, 12)` can never be equal to a string of length 13:

```
>> c1 = "* BEGIN DATE "
>> WScript.Echo Len(c1)
>>
13
```

**WRT comment:**

First you have to learn to count:

```
>> WScript.Echo """" & Mid(s1, 21) & """"
>>
"1/07/13"
```

Then you should put some diagnostic output into your script to check your assumptions, e.g.

```
WScript.Echo """" & Left|Mid(strLine, <decent number>) & """"
```

**WRT edit:**

Your

```
 If (Instr(strLine, 13) = "BEGIN DATE") Then
```

compares a string of length 13 to "BEGIN DATE" - length 10, no "* " prefix.

Comment: sooo, i've tryied to write: `If (Left(strLine, 13) = "* BEGIN DATE ") Then objOutputTS.WriteLine(Mid(strLine, 21))` but nothing change! the second part maybe is wrong. I mean `objOutputTS.WriteLine(Mid(strLine, 21))`